# Models in an Angular project

Tags: angular

I am looking into the Core/Shared/Feature design pattern for designing large, scalable applications in Angular, and I am a bit confused on the subject of models.

Is there a consensus on which module they should be added?

I have read one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040341/what-should-be-included-in-core-shared-and-feature-modules) that states that models should only go into the feature modules. However, if models are to be re-used, where then should they go, instead: the core module or the shared model?

Since the core module is reserved for singleton items, does it make any sense to store any models there?

As a follow-up, should models that are only used once per feature be stored in their respective feature module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what makes conceptual sense. If you have a model that is specific to a particular feature, it should live in the module of that feature. If several features need to use the same model, that model could live in a separate feature module on which the others depend. If you have models that are needed across the entire app, then it might go in a module called "core" which is accessible to every other module in the app.

As a general rule of thumb, try to keep things isolated into their own modules as much as possible. Code can get messy if you start putting everything into one "core" or "shared" module.